# How can I get the final evaluated material color of each face?

Tags: python, materials, scripting, shaders, shader-nodes

I want to be able to get the final evaluated color for each face regardless of what shader node setup I have. I just want to get the final color result flowing into the Base Color socket of the Principled BSDF. I have made this script to try get the color of the evaluated object and evaluated material. Is this possible? I simply want the final Base Color or diffuse color value for each face. Theoretically should this not be possible with Python or Geonodes or anything else?

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
eval_obj = obj.evaluated_get(dg)

for face in eval_obj.data.polygons:
    mat = obj.material_slots[face.material_index].material
    evaluated_material = mat.evaluated_get(dg)
    color = evaluated_material.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs["Base Color"].default_value
    print("Face:", face.index, face.material_index, evaluated_material.name, color)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This value is computed at runtime and AFAIK streamlined by the CPU / GPU to the material output per pixel, it isn't computed per face and there is no way to tap into the workflow to extract a value at a specific node, so I'm afraid you can't get this information unless you bake the result to an image texture and read the color value.

Comment: interesting! i did not know you can do this i will research how to bake it via python! thanks so much for sharing this info